# Android onActivityResult causing multiple instances of same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities,`MessagesActivity`, `MessagesAttachPhotoActivity` and `ImageGalleryActivity`. From `MessagesActivity`, I start `MessagesAttachPhotoActivity`  as follows,

```
  intent = new Intent(this, MessagesAttachPhotoActivity.class);
  bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt("Request", MessageThread.MessageType.IMAGE);
  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  startActivityForResult(intent, MessageThread.MessageType.IMAGE);
```

Then from`MessagesAttachPhotoActivity`, I start `ImageGalleryActivity` as follows;

```
intent = new Intent(this, MessagesAttachPhotoActivity.class);
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Request", MessageThread.MessageType.IMAGE);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, MessageThread.MessageType.IMAGE);
```

In `ImageGalleryActivity`, this is how I am returning the result to`MessagesAttachPhotoActivity`

```
Intent photoIntent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("item", imagePath);
photoIntent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, photoIntent);
finish();
```

Problem is,evrytime I go back from `ImageGalleryActivity`, a new Instance of `MessagesAttachPhotoActivity` is created. How can I avoid this? I want to visit `ImageGalleryActivity` about twenty times from `MessagesAttachPhotoActivity`. Please, someone help.

Comment: How do you go back to MessagesAttachPhotoActivity from ImageGalleryActivity?

Comment: @Chol please check my edit

Comment: But... from MessagesAttachPhotoActiivty your are launching again same acitivity: intent = new Intent(this, MessagesAttachPhotoActivity.class);

Comment: And in ImageGalleryActivity, what have you put after the setResult()?

Comment: You will need to put more code, and double check the intent = new Intent(this, MessagesAttachPhotoActivity.class); from MessagesAttachPhotoActivity class

Comment: @Chol actually you spotted the error. Something so simple yet wasted more than four hours of my time. It was here  intent = new Intent(this, MessagesAttachPhotoActivity.class);

Comment: @Chol thanks. I guess am fatigued.